# Writing binding providers in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

In his [KnockoutJs 1.3 beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/) post, Steve Sanderson has an example of using Binding providers ("5. Binding providers (and hence external bindings)") where he makes a comment in the JSFiddle JavaScript tab that says "// This syntax would be way more succinct with CoffeeScript".

How would this actually be accomplished?

```
// This syntax would be way more succinct with CoffeeScript
ko.bindingConventions.conventions(".person-editor", {
    ".person-editor"  : { 'with': myViewModel.person },
    ".first-name"     : function(person) { return { value: person.firstName } },
    ".last-name"      : function(person) { return { value: person.lastName } }
});

ko.bindingConventions.conventions("#weather-list", {
    "#weather-list"    : { 'with': myViewModel.weather },
    ".cities-list"     : function(weather) { return { foreach: weather.cities } },  
    ".city"            : function(item) { return { text: item.city } },      
    ".temp"            : function(item) { return { text: item.temperature } },        
    ".add-city"        : { click: function() { this.addItem() } }  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ko.bindingConvenrions.conventions ".person-editor"
   ".person-editor"  :  
      'with'   :  myViewModel.person
   ".first-name"     : ( person ) ->
                        value : person.firstName
   ".last-name"      : ( person ) ->
                        value : person.lastName
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be even better with simpler spacing and single quotes where
interpolation is not being used (a hint to the reader that these strings are
literal). Grouping related functions can add clarity, too, if you end up with
an unruly number of properties.

```coffee
ko.bindingConventions.conventions '.person-editor',
  '.person-editor':
    with: myViewModel.person
  '.first-name': (person) ->
    value: person.firstName
  '.last-name': (person) ->
    value: person.lastName

ko.bindingConventions.conventions '#weather-list',
  '#weather-list':
    with: myViewModel.weather
  '.add-city':
    click: ->
      @addItem()
  '.cities-list': (weather) ->
    foreach: weather.cities
  '.city': (item) ->
    text: item.city
  '.temp': (item) ->
    text: item.temperature
```